# Ensure returned pointer is const, without throwing warnings

Tags: c, constants, compiler-warnings, rvalue, function-declaration

My goal is to define a clean API for my library.
One of my function returns a pointer that shall not be modified with pointers arithmetic.
To do so at compile-time, I was planning on using the `const` keyword in the function prototype.

Here's a naive example:

```
int global_var = 12;

int* const access_global_var(){ return &global_var;}

int main(void) {
  int* const ptr = access_global_var();

  *ptr = 15;  //< Should be valid 
  ptr++;      //< Should be Invalid 
  return 0;
}
```

It works as expected: the compiler throws an error at `ptr++;`.

**Problem:**
When compiling with the `-Wextra` clang/gcc flag, I get the following warnings:

```c
warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect
```

Is this warning correct? Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
As warnings are treated errors in my project, this is, as you can expect, problematic.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to qualify return values.  The variable you assign the return value to is where you need qualification.

Comment: I agree that I don't need it. But is there a way to enforce that user will use const with its variable­?

Comment: Even if you could force the caller to assign the function value only to a `const`, effectively requiring `int * const x = access_global_var();`, the caller could then do `int *y = x;`. Think about what you are asking as if the function returned a simple `int`, not a pointer. Would there be any use in insisting that a caller could assign a return, value, say 3, only to a `const int x = 3;` and never be allowed to use their own `x` for anything else? They have to be able to use `x` in expressions, yes? Say `x+4`? That should not be `const`, too, should it?…

Comment: … Suppose you could force a `const int x = 3;` and somehow propagate this to disallow `int y = x;`. But, if `x+4` is not also forced to be `const`, then they could write `x+0` to remove the `const`, thus doing `int y = x+0;`. Or, if you disallowed that, then `int y = x+4-4;`. Similarly, the pointer could be `int *x = access_global_var() + 1 - 1;`. Or `int *x = access_global_var + HardToEvaluateFunction();`, which would prevent the compiler from knowing the function returns zero. From a language design perspective, this request is not feasible.

Answer (score 4):

The return type of the function

```
int* const access_global_var(){ return &global_var;}
```

does not make sense.

If you will remove the qualifier const in any case you may not write for example

```
++access_global_var();
```

because the function returns an rvalue.

But even if you have the qualifier const you may write

```
int *p = access_global_var();
```

and then

```
++p;
```

That is you may assign a constant value to a non-constant object.

So the compiler warns that the qualifier used in the return type does not make sense and may be removed without changing the ,logic.

Comment: I understand lvalues.
 The fact that you can write `int *p = access_global_var();` is the problem that I want to solve.

Comment: @gberth Why is it a problem? Why may not the user increase the pointer? He does not change the global variable by increasing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you really want to force this upon developers (who will have no problem getting around this restriction if they want to), you can always use a function-like macro to try to enforce this.  If you want the macro to be specific to a particular global var, like in your example, it might look like this:

```
#define create_global_var_accessor(ACCESSOR) \
    int *const ACCESSOR = &global_var

int global_var = 12;

int main(void) {
    create_global_var_accessor(ptr);

    *ptr = 15;  //< Should be valid 
    ptr++;      //< Should be Invalid 
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise if you want something more generic, you can pass in the target global var along with its type (or use GNU `typeof` extension):

```
#define create_global_var_accessor(TYPE, ACCESSOR, ACCESSEE) \
    TYPE *const ACCESSOR = &(ACCESSEE)

int global_var = 12;

int main(void) {
    create_global_var_accessor(int, ptr, global_var);

    *ptr = 15;  //< Should be valid 
    ptr++;      //< Should be Invalid 
    return 0;
}
```

That aside, I'll echo Vlad from Moscow in stating that I don't think this is a problem in need of a solution.